# Network throughput and message delay

Tags: analysis, network

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the throughput. Throughput is defined as the rate (bits/sec) bits are transferred between a sender and receiver; also, . I have a source node and a destination node, $k+1$ nodes all together with $k-1$ intermediary nodes. There are $k$ links between each pair of nodes and to transmit one bit it takes $\tau$ seconds and the bandwidth of each link is $W$ bits/sec.

Before a single message can be sent the source sends a connection request message, the destination replies with an accept/deny message to the source, and then the real message transfer begins. Following the source's message a connection disconnect message is sent. These 3 messages are $H$ bits long and occur so that the destination must receive the entire message before the next one is sent out.

First I simplify the problem by only considering the connection between 1 source and 1 destination node. For 1 message that is $H$ bits long the time taken to transmit the entire message should be $H$ bits * $\tau$ seconds. So, to transmit 3 messages across k nodes I have a total time of $3k(H*\tau)$seconds. From here I'm not sure how to calculate the throughput and get lost with the unit cancelation to get to bits/sec.

Any ideas on how to manipulate the problem to get a throughput in bits/sec?

EDIT: Problem explanation.
[image]

Comment: From my understanding $\tau$ s is only the propagation delay within one link. In steady state after all handshaking, the overall throughput should be $W$ bps.

Comment: To clarify: when a message is sent from node $1$ to $k+1$, there are three connection messages along with the content message associated with every hop, is that right?  One of the difficulties that it seems you are having is that you are multiplying $H*\tau$, having units "bits$*$seconds" when it would make more sense to say "$\tau=\tfrac HW$" or something similar.

Comment: There is no pipelining so the messages would have to travel one at a time through each node/hop. So once message 1 reaches its destination, only then can message 2 be sent.

Comment: Does message 2 have to wait for the acknowledgment of message 1, before message 2 can be sent?

Comment: Well message 2, accept or deny request of connection, can only be sent by the final destination node. So I'm sure that means it has to wait for the receipt of message 1.

Answer (score 1):

In steady state after handshaking, a message of maximum segment size ($MSS$) can be sent to the destination by time

$$\text{propagation delay} + \text{transmission delay} = k\tau + k\frac{MSS}{W}$$

The return acknowledgement has a delay of

$$\text{propagation delay} + \text{transmission delay} = k\tau + k\frac{H}{W}$$

The sum of these two gives the whole round trip time. And the actual message length sent without header should be $MSS-H$, which gives throughput

$$\text{throughput} = \frac{MSS-H}{2k\tau+k\frac{MSS+H}{W}}$$

Of course there are quite a lot of assumptions and simplifications here.

Comment: I edited my post for a better explanation of the question. I think your answer may have overlooked a couple of things.